# Warning Error Message in Email Template

Tags: email-template

I am getting error message when i am trying to insert template in salesforce while sending email.It was not happened before.Please help me to ignore this error warning message template in salesforce.

[image]

Anyone please guide me how to ignore this warning message in salesforce

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box option. This occurs whenever you try to insert an email template with something filled out in your current email. You can vote for this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PZGKQA4) which asks for there to be an option.

There's also this slightly different [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpaeAAC) where the comments seem to indicate some sort of inconsistency with seeing this pop up versus not with regards to certain templates.

Comment: It was not happened before , it is occuring recently

Comment: Then, I'd create a support case, if you're able to, to confirm what to expect. I edited my answer to include another idea where others in the comment mention this appearing for some templates and not others.